How do I keep my tikz drawing on the page?
I am just learning tikz and I made a picture that I would like to add to a paper I have to write. However, I cannot figure out how to get the figure to center itself on the page. Currently when it compiles the right most 8th is off the right hand side of the page.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}     % Core package for drawing
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}  % For drawing trees easily
\usetikzlibrary{trees}   % To manage tree structures
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}  % For arrow customization
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % For relative positioning of nodes
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % For braces and other decorations

% Define styles for nodes
\tikzset{
    vertex/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
    final/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
    decision/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
    every edge/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=1.2]}, draw, thick},
    level distance = 15mm,  % Reduced vertical spacing
    sibling distance = 35mm  % Reduced horizontal spacing
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 15mm and 35mm,  % Adjusted to fit the page
    vertex/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
    final/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
    decision/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
    every edge/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=1.2]}, draw, thick}]

        % Nodes
        \node (R)   [vertex]  {RVR};
        \node (V1)    [decision, below= of R]  {V};
        \node (MVL)   [vertex, below left= of V1]  {MV};
        \node (MVF)  [vertex, below right= of V1]   {MV};
        \node (V2L)   [decision, below = of MVL]    {V};
        \node (V2R)    [decision, below = of MVF] {V};
        \node (Final Left)  [final, below = of V2L] {CE};
        \node (Final Right) [final, below = of V2R] {CE};

        % Edges
        \path (R) edge[->] node[midway, right] {Discussion} (V1);
        \path (V1) edge[->] node[midway, left] {ME} (MVL);
        \path (V1) edge[->] node[midway, right] {CE} (MVF);
        \path (MVL) edge[->] node[midway, right] {Discussion} (V2L);
        \path (MVF) edge[->] node[midway, left] {Discussion} (V2R);
        \path (V2L) edge[->] node[midway, right] {MV} (Final Left);
        \path (V2R) edge[->] node[midway, left] {MV} (Final Right);

        % Draw symmetric edges
        \draw (Final Left) edge [out=180,in=140,looseness=1] (R);
        \draw (Final Right) edge [out=0,in=40,looseness=1] (R);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Any other advice on how to make it look better would be apreciated.

To centre something inside a float (e.g. a figure or table), use
\centering

The basic problem here is that TeX thinks the picture is too wide for the page. If you look at the log or on the terminal, you will have warnings about overfull boxes with line numbers where they occur in your source.
Here's a simple way to help diagnose this kind of problem: put the picture in a visible box:

The problem is caused by the curved lines. PGF adds additional points to the picture, which count towards the bounding box, even though they are invisible. One way to avoid this is to draw the lines outside the bounding box. Note that you must ensure things fit and look right if you do this because, as far as TeX is concerned your picture will now be smaller than it really is. In a case like this, though, where there is nothing alongside, it is probably fine. You could alternatively cut out just the extra horizontal space, but I'd only fuss with that if necessary. Most likely the picture ends up on a page of its own anyway.
To draw the curved lines outside the bounding box add
 \path [use as bounding box] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);

before drawing them. This works because the curved lines are drawn last. If you went on to draw additional things afterwards, we'd need to adjust the solution. The way it works is it tells PGF that from now on, nothing counts towards the bounding box. So the box is fixed from this point.

\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725756/
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}  % For arrow customization
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % For relative positioning of nodes
% Define styles for nodes
\tikzset{
  vertex/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  final/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  decision/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  every edge/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=1.2]}, draw, thick},
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  % \fbox{% to draw a frame around the picture for debugging (as shown)
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 15mm and 35mm,  % Adjusted to fit the page
      ]

      % Nodes
      \node (R)   [vertex]  {RVR};
      \node (V1)    [decision, below= of R]  {V};
      \node (MVL)   [vertex, below left= of V1]  {MV};
      \node (MVF)  [vertex, below right= of V1]   {MV};
      \node (V2L)   [decision, below = of MVL]    {V};
      \node (V2R)    [decision, below = of MVF] {V};
      \node (Final Left)  [final, below = of V2L] {CE};
      \node (Final Right) [final, below = of V2R] {CE};

      % Edges
      \path (R) edge[->] node[midway, right] {Discussion} (V1);
      \path (V1) edge[->] node[midway, left] {ME} (MVL);
      \path (V1) edge[->] node[midway, right] {CE} (MVF);
      \path (MVL) edge[->] node[midway, right] {Discussion} (V2L);
      \path (MVF) edge[->] node[midway, left] {Discussion} (V2R);
      \path (V2L) edge[->] node[midway, right] {MV} (Final Left);
      \path (V2R) edge[->] node[midway, left] {MV} (Final Right);

      \path [use as bounding box] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);

      % Draw symmetric edges

      \draw (Final Left) edge [out=180,in=140,looseness=1] (R);
      \draw (Final Right) edge [out=0,in=40,looseness=1] (R);

    \end{tikzpicture}%
  % }
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

A few more comments on your code.

You are unnecessarily duplicating style definitions. If you define them in the preamble, you don't need to repeat them in the picture unless you want to change them as a one-off. If they are repeatedly used in many pictures, keep them in the preamble. If they are just for this picture, don't put them in the preamble.
Personally, I would not use basic tikz to draw trees, at least if you need to draw several. You are not actually using tikz-qtree or trees. You are not drawing this as a tree, as far as tikz is concerned, at all. This is fine for a one-off, but not the way to go if you draw many of them. tikz-qtree is one option, but forest would be my choice.

Here's the same tree rendered in forest with a little automation.

\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725756/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}  % For arrow customization
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % For relative positioning of nodes
% Define styles for nodes
\tikzset{
  vertex/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  final/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  decision/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  every edge/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=1.2]}, draw, thick},
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      edge+=every edge,
      l sep'=15mm,
      s sep'=35mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    },
    delay={%
      where edge label={}{}{
        split option={edge label}{:}{temptoksa,temptoksb},
        edge label/.process={RRw2{temptoksa}{temptoksb}{node [midway,font=\sffamily,#1]{#2}}},
      },
    },
    [RVR, vertex, name=R
      [V, decision, name=V1, edge label=right:Discussion
        [MV, name=MVL, vertex, edge label={above,xshift=-5pt}:ME
          [V, decision,name=V2L, edge label=right:Discussion
            [CE, name=Final Left, final, edge label=right:MV]
          ]
        ]
        [MV, name=MVR, vertex, edge label={above,xshift=5pt}:CE
          [V, decision,name=V2R, edge label=left:Discussion
            [CE, name=Final Right, final, edge label=left:MV]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \path [use as bounding box] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    \draw (Final Left) edge [out=180,in=140,looseness=1] (R);
    \draw (Final Right) edge [out=0,in=40,looseness=1] (R);
  \end{forest}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Finally, this code produces the same tree more automatically still. It defines a forest style, decision tree which colours the nodes appropriately, and uses 'nodewalk' names rather than naming nodes explicitly. These are basically names for positions in the tree e.g. !r is the root node, !F is the first leaf, !L is the last leaf and so on.
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725756/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}  % For arrow customization
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}  % For relative positioning of nodes
% Define styles for nodes
\tikzset{
  vertex/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  final/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  decision/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=yellow!20, text width=5em, align=center, minimum height=2.5em, font=\bfseries},
  every edge/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=1.2]}, draw, thick},
}
\forestset{%
  decision tree/.style={%
    for tree={
      edge+=every edge,
      l sep'=15mm,
      s sep'=35mm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
    },
    delay={%
      vertex,
      for descendants={
        if n children=0 {final}{
          if={> On= {!u.n children}{1}} {vertex}{decision},
        },
        if edge label={}{}{
          split option={edge label}{:}{temptoksa,temptoksb},
          edge label/.process={RRw2{temptoksa}{temptoksb}{node [midway,font=\sffamily,##1]{##2}}},
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    decision tree,
    [RVR
      [V, edge label=right:Discussion
        [MV, edge label={above,xshift=-5pt}:ME
          [V, edge label=right:Discussion
            [CE, edge label=right:MV]
          ]
        ]
        [MV, edge label={above,xshift=5pt}:CE
          [V, edge label=left:Discussion
            [CE, edge label=left:MV]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \path [use as bounding box] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    \draw (!F) edge [out=180,in=140,looseness=1] (!r);
    \draw (!L) edge [out=0,in=40,looseness=1] (!r);
  \end{forest}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Excellent explanation +1. Thank you

@MS-SPO why, thank you.

You can exclude the curvy lines from the bounding box by just adding the overlay option to them, as in \draw[overlay] ...;.  This is simpler than modifying the bounding box explicitly, and will work even if those lines are not the last to be drawn.

See also pgfinterruptboundingbox (page 1079).

@adl I think I was thinking that I might want to set the bounding box after drawing the curves and catch the updated vertical extent. that would be too great, but might have been useful. but then I realised this would probably end up on its own page, so there didn't seem much point and so overlay would, indeed, have been simpler.

@JohnKormylo yes, if you need to draw stuff you want to count afterwards, that's the way to go.
